# Byte data getting truncated before getting inserted/updated into column of datatype varbinary(max)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, varbinarymax

I am inserting Binary data into the one of my tables with a column having datatype varbinary(max).

The total length of the binary data which I am inserting is 610154 characters long.

While after inserting the data either through the code or manually by SSMS, only a part of that gets inserted (43679 characters only).

I did check if there are any triggers or constraints tied to the column in which I am trying to insert the data to, but there aren't any.

As per my previous search on stackoverflow , the (max) means I could insert 2^31 bytes. 
I also confirmed by looking into the trace that I am sending in the complete information (610154 length)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly how are you inserting the data?  Can you post your code? What does `DATALENGTH()` tell you the inserted column length is?

Comment: @BaconBits - Yup, the DATALENGTH() in the code gives me the exact number of bytes I am trying to insert. Some how I am not able to see that when I select the value.

Comment: It means your INSERT is working just fine, and the data is in the DB.  It's that [SSMS isn't displaying the entire record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880324/copying-a-large-field-varbinarymax-to-file-clipboard).  If you query with PowerShell, for example, you should see the full value.  There may be a limitation on the provider you're using in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that all of your data is actually being inserted, but somehow SSMS is only returning a portion of the data when you run a query to check if it is there? Check the TEXTSIZE property by running the following...

> SELECT @@TEXTSIZE

Or within the SSMS Options...

[image]

What is TEXTSIZE set at for you?

Noel

Comment: That's the same for me.. 2147483647